# can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj

I got an error when I use aspect with springboot 2.0.5.RELEASE,but it works totally fine at 1.3.5.RELEASE
and only @DeclareParents this annotation has such problem

below are my codes

raw Interface

```
public interface Performance {
public void perform();
}
```

the implement

```
@Component
public class PerformanceImpl implements Performance {

/* 
 * @see com.lyman.example.demo.api.Performance#perform()
 */
@Override
public void perform() {
    System.out.println("=================performance start=========");

}

}
```

the new interface

```
public interface Encoreable {
void performEncore();
}
```

new implement

```
@Component
public class DefaultEncoreable implements Encoreable {

/* 
 * @see com.lyman.example.demo.concert.Encoreable#performEncore()
 */
@Override
public void performEncore() {
    System.out.println("perform the encore");

  }

 }
```

aspect bean

```
@Aspect
public class EncoreableIntroducer {
@DeclareParents(value = "com.lyman.example.demo.concert.Performance+", 
defaultImpl = DefaultEncoreable.class)
public static Encoreable encoreable;
}
```

java config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy 
@ComponentScan
public class RootConfig {



@Bean
public EncoreableIntroducer encoreableIntroducer() {
    return new EncoreableIntroducer();
}
}
```

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.lyman.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.44</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
     <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and the errors comes out when I start my project

```
2019-03-14 18:30:15.088  WARN 20500 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonCodecCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/codec/CodecsAutoConfiguration$JacksonCodecConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration$JacksonCodecConfiguration$$Lambda$324.1850477964
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
2019-03-14 18:30:15.089  INFO 20500 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2019-03-14 18:30:15.094  INFO 20500 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-03-14 18:30:15.133  INFO 20500 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-14 18:30:15.149 ERROR 20500 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonCodecCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/codec/CodecsAutoConfiguration$JacksonCodecConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration$JacksonCodecConfiguration$$Lambda$324.1850477964
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.lyman.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration$JacksonCodecConfiguration$$Lambda$324.1850477964
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ExceptionBasedMessageHandler.handleMessage(ReflectionWorld.java:211) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar:1.8.13]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Lint$Kind.signal(Lint.java:340) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar:1.8.13]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.raiseCantFindType(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:232) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar:1.8.13]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.getDeclaredInterfaces(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:86) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar:1.8.13]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getDirectSupertypes(ResolvedType.java:82) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar:1.8.13]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePattern.matchesSubtypes(TypePattern.java:178) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar:1.8.13]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePattern.matchesStatically(TypePattern.java:130) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar:1.8.13]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.TypePatternMatcherImpl.matches(TypePatternMatcherImpl.java:31) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar:1.8.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.TypePatternClassFilter.matches(TypePatternClassFilter.java:102) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.ClassFilters$IntersectionClassFilter.matches(ClassFilters.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:284) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:269) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:310) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:126) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:76) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:352) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:304) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1703) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Remove `spring-aop` and `spring-tx` and use `spring-boot-starter-aop` . With `spring-tx` you are mixing different versions of Spring never do things like that (regardless of the framework in use). Using the `spring-boot-starter-aop` you can also remove the aspectj dependency. The `spring-boot-starter` dependency is also a duplicate (it is part of all starters) so remove that as well.

Comment: it didn't work for me ,after I remove  the  duplicated dependency,the same error comes out

Answer (score 0):

you can try change the value of the `@DeclareParents` from `com.lyman.example.demo.concert.Performance+` to
`com.lyman.example.demo.concert.Performance`

Comment: after remove the character '+', the project can start up successfully, but can't cast PerformanceImpl to Encoreable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
`com.lyman.example.demo.concert.Performance+`
to
`com.lyman.example.demo.concert.PerformanceImpl`

Solution 2:
ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration`

Delete your Codecs dependency in build.gradle or pom.xml.
OR
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = CodecsAutoConfiguration)`

It worked for me, but I don't know why